# F# records, usage, code clarity

Tags: f#

Background:

I find myself harnessing F# Records a lot. Currently I am working on a project for packet dissection & replay of a proprietary binary protocol (a protocol that is very strangely designed ...).

We define the skeleton record for the packet.

```
type bytes = byte array
type packetSkeleton = {
    part1 : bytes
    part2 : bytes 
    ... }
```

Now, it is easy to use this to 'dissect' our packet, (really just giving names to the byte fields).

```
let dissect (raw : bytes) =
  let slice a b = raw.[a..b]
  { part1 = slice 0 4
    part2 = slice 4 5
    ... }
```

This works perfectly even for longish packets, we can even use some neat recursive functions if there is a predicable pattern to the slicing.

So I dissect the packet, pull out the fields that I need and create a packet based off the packetSkeleton using the fields I took from the dissection, which by now is starting to look a bit awkward:

```
let createAuthStub a b c d e f g h ... =
   { part1 = a; part2 = b
     part3 = d; ...
   }
```

Then, after creating the populated stub, I need to deserialise it to a form that can be put on the wire:

```
(* packetSkeleton -> byte array *)
let deserialise (packet : packetSkeleton) =
  [| packet.part1; packet.part2; ... |]

let xab = dissect buf
let authStub = createAuthStub xab.part1 1 2 xab.part9 ...

deserialise authStub |> send
```

So it ends up that I have 3 areas, the record type, the creation of the record for a given packet, and the deserialised byte array. Something tells me that this is a poor design choice on my part in terms of code clarity, and I can already feel it starting to shoot me in the foot even at this early stage.

**Questions:**

a) Am I using the correct datatype for such a project? Is my approach correct?
  b) Should I just give up on trying to make this code feel clean?

As I am kinda coding this by touch and go, I would appreciate some insights!

P.S I realise that this problem is quite suited for C, but F# is more fun (additionally verification of the dissector later on sounds appealing)!

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `createAuthStub`. It takes a bunch of `packetSkeleton` fields and returns a new `packetSkeleton`?

Comment: yes, but it is for creating the packet, so after you dissect the incoming packet, you can use components of the dissected packet to create a new skeleton, for example a challenge response scenario where you send your first packet, get a response with a cookie in it, then that cookies is used in your subsequent requests. I probably just made this more unclear.

Comment: Then why not change `createAuthStub` to accept `packetSkeleton` instead of passing each field as a separate parameter?

Comment: hmm, because I am needing to send other fields to createAuthStub, for example I only need a few fields (probably just 2) from the first received packetSkeleton (a cookie value and a type value), the rest of the fields can be arbitrary for example: let xab = dissect buf
let authStub = createAuthStub xab.part1 1 2 xab.part9 , i am sending  part of the packetSkeleton to createAuthStub, but also sending values 1 and 2 that are not from the received packetSkeleton

Comment: Depending on how large a packet could be it seems `packetSkeleton` could grow unwieldy. Is it worth having the type? Assuming you only have a few functions, would working with bytes be awful?

Comment: hmm, that is a good point, working with bytes isn't probably too bad, and is probably a lot easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a packet could be rather large `packetSkeleton` might grow unwieldy. Another option is to work with the raw bytes and define a module that reads/writes each part.

```ml
module Packet
  let Length = 42
  let GetPart1 src = src.[0..3]
  let SetPart1 src dst = Array.blit src 0 dst 0 4
  let GetPart2 src = src.[4..5]
  let SetPart2 src dst = Array.blit src 0 dst 4 2
  ...

open Packet 

let createAuthStub bytes b c =
  let resp = Array.zeroCreate Packet.Length
  SetPart1 (GetPart1 bytes) 
  SetPart2 b resp
  SetPart3 c resp
  SetPart4 (GetPart9 bytes) 
  resp
```

This removes the need for de/serialization functions (and probably helps performance a bit).

#### EDIT

Creating a wrapper type is another option

```ml
type Packet(bytes: byte[]) =
  new() = Packet(Array.zeroCreate Packet.Length)
  static member Length = 42
  member x.Part1
    with get() = bytes.[0..3]
    and set value = Array.blit value 0 bytes 0 4
    ...
```

which might reduce code a bit:

```ml
let createAuthStub (req: Packet) b c =
  let resp = Packet()
  resp.Part1 <- req.Part1
  resp.Part2 <- b
  resp.Part3 <- c
  resp.Part4 <- req.Part9
  resp
```

Comment: I believe I will take the approach that you first listed eventually, although while I agree with wrapper in the second part of your answer as something that reduces code, for me personally, I prefer your first approach.

Comment: +1 Yes, I think that using just byte array (possibly with a current index?) is the best representation for efficient processing. Note that it broadly also fits in the scheme I described - except that your _domain model_ is now a byte array with some associated processing functions (in a module).

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is essentially sound - but of course, it is difficult to tell without knowing more details.

I think one key idea that shows in your code and that is key to functional architecture is the separation between types (used to model the problem domain) and the processing functionality that creates the values of the domain model, processes it and formats them.

In your case:

- The types `bytes` and `packetSkeleton` model the problem domain
- The function `createAuthStub` processes your domain (and I agree with Daniel that it might be more readable if it took the whole `packetSkeleton` as an argument)
- The function `deserialize` turns your domain back to bytes

I think this way of structuring code is quite good, because it separates different concerns of the program. I even wrote an article that tries to describe this as a [more general programming approach](http://tomasp.net/blog/type-first-development.aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Now I can stop procrastinating and keep coding! (ok maybe a little more procrastinating) I read your entry on first type dev, i really liked it ! Was cool to see units of measure being used with records like that.